# Matricial product not commutative unlike tensor 2D

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, matrix-calculus

I would like to know why,as a general rule and which under conditions, one says that tensor product is commutative unlike matricial product.

For example, for a product of 2 matrices, we get the element (i,j) by writing (with Einstein notations) :

$$C_{ij} = A_{ik} B_{kj}$$

and

$$D_{ij} = B_{ik} A_{kj}$$

So $C_{ij} \neq D_{ij}$

But with tensors, it seems that it doesn't matter to multiply the first tensor by the second or the contrary :

$$C_{ik}= A_{il}B_{lk} = B_{lk}A_{il}=B_{kl}A_{li}=D_{ki}$$

You can notice that I have supposed A and B as symetric tensors.

**What are the rules for a tensor to respect for not consider the order in multiplications and get commutative product (unlike matricial product**) ?

Taking symetric tensors is sufficient ? I don't think so since there are also antsymetric tensors (like Maxwell tensor).

If someone could give me a simple example highlighting this issue ?

Any clarifications is welcome, regards.

Comment: Your "tensor product" is the same as the matrix product. The actual tensor product would have 4 indices for $C$ (so the result is not a matrix): $$C_{ijkl} = A_{ij}B_{kl}$$

Comment: -@mr_e_man it may be a contraction between $j$ and $k$, such that we could write : $C_{ijkl} = C_{il}=A_{in}B_{nl}$, couldn't we ?

Comment: $C$ is not equal to its contraction! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Contraction

Comment: The first contraction of $C$ is the matrix product, and the second contraction is the trace $\text{tr}(AB)$.

Comment: -@mr_e_man ok, you're right. I can't find an example showing the cases where order of factors matters (for matrices) and those when order doesn't matter (like for tensors), could you illustrate please this issue ?

Comment: The order matters in both cases. But the tensor product $A\otimes B$ differs from $B\otimes A$ only in the arrangement of terms. For example, consider the tensor product of vectors $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 10 & 0 \\ 3 & 5 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ $$\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 3 \\ 10 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$